# How can I get autotest to notice changes in subdirectories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autotest, zentest, specifications

I have some submodules organized like this:

```
|-- app
|   |-- models
|   |   |-- foo
|   |   |   |-- foo-1.rb
|   |   |   |-- foo-2.rb
|   |   |   |-- foo-3.rb
|   |   |-- foo.rb
```

How can I get autotest to notice changes made to foo-*.rb, and then run the appropriate specs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate your autotest/discover.rb file with mappings:

```
Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |at|
  # match the model name (the whole Regex object is in _)
  at.add_mapping(%r%^app/models/(foo)/\w+\.rb$%, true) do |filename, _|
    "spec/models/#{_[1]}_spec.rb"
  end
end
```

You can find more how to use the mappings and hooks [in the API docs](http://zentest.rubyforge.org/ZenTest/Autotest.html).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should investigate watchr

https://github.com/mynyml/watchr

It's similar to autotest, while being quite a bit more configurable and more easily setup.

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting alternative is [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard).